# Relation between SABR parameters and Taylor expansion parameters

Tags: volatility, stochastic-calculus, sabr

Suppose a SABR model framework (with $\beta=1$)

$$dF_t=\sigma_t S_t dW^{S}_{t}$$

$$d\sigma_t=\alpha \sigma_t dW^{\sigma}_{t}$$

$$dW^{S}_{t}dW^{\sigma}_{t}=\rho dt$$

I know that the Implied Volatility induced by SABR model can be expressed in a very readable way, by the following equation:

$$\sigma^{SABR}(x)= a +bx +\frac{1}{2}cx^{2}+O(x^{3})$$

$a$ is at-the-forward implied volatility level, $b$ is implied volatility skew, $c$ is implied volatility convexity.

Then, the relation between model parameters and the $a,b,c$ parameters is:

$$\sigma_{0}=a$$

$$\alpha= \sqrt{6b^{2}+3ac}$$

$$\rho=\frac{2b}{\sqrt{6b^{2}+3ac}}$$

Could you please provide a detailed derivation of the three equations above relating model parameters ($\alpha, \sigma_{0}, \rho$) with ($a, b, c$) parameters?

Thank you

Comment: The way this and a [related](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70036/asymptotic-formula-for-local-volatility-in-sabr-model) question is formulated isn't very enticing. Where are these formulas from? Have they withstood a practical test? Can you start from the well-known [SABR implied vol formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABR_volatility_model#Asymptotic_solution) ?  More background from you could help.

Comment: Yes, the formulas are used in practice. I want to know where they come from, what is the rationale to get to them.